# Two table filter

Tags: python, django

I try to filter the Author with the class Book that has the specific category, but I can't get the exact category.

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    foreignkey = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="auth")
class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

**views.py**

```
book = models.Book.objects.filter(category = 'Space')
author = models.Author.objects.filter(author_id__in = book )
```

Comment: `book = models.Book.objects.filter(category = 'Space')` but your category in your Book class is `models.IntegerField()`. Either filter `category=<int>` or change category to `models.CharField()`. Also, what are you trying with your Author filter?

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


books = Book.objects.values('author_id',flat=True).filter(category='Space')
authors = Author.objects.filter(pk__in=books)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')

class Author(models.Model):
    # pks are added automatically
```

In views.py

```
books = models.Book.objects.filter(category='Space')
authors = models.Author.objects.filter(pk__in=[b.author_id for b in books])
```

Comment: 'Book' has no attribute name id, I modify it to `b.author` still not work.